# how to search parameter from URL NodeJs and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

http://localhost:9000/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=advertising&utm_campaign=jobpost

or

http://localhost:9000/test/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=advertising&utm_campaign=jobpost

or

http://localhost:9000/blah/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=advertising&utm_campaign=jobpost

How to get and check whether `utm_source` is in URL or not in NodeJS/Express? I've tried like that but not successful.

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    if (req.query.utm_source === 'facebook') {
        res.send('1) id: ' + req.query.utm_source);
    } else {
        res.redirect('/blah');
    }
});
```

Comment: How is it not successful, what are you getting ?

Comment: @adeneo please check my question again cos I edit it. It got 'redirect loop' error.

Comment: You're matching ALL routes with `app.get('/*')`, remove the * and you won't get the redirect  loop error anymore.

Comment: So, if `req.query.utm_source` isn't "facebook", you end up in the `else` part, where you redirect to `/blah`, but the posted route matches anything, so you end up right back where you were, in the same `else` clause, redirecting back ...... to the same `else` clause, over and over.